# Return even if inner join returns no result

Tags: mysql

Good day!

I have the following tables:

**devices** (id, device_name, device_uid, device_type, account_id)

**device_data** (id_device, timestamp, value1, value2, value3)

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM devices AS d 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM device_data 
            WHERE timestamp IN (SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
                                FROM device_data)) AS dd ON d.id = dd.id_device
```

With the above query I get all devices and their last entry from the device_data table. But if the device has no values in the device_data table yet, this is not captured by the query. But I expect an output like this:

| id | device_name | device_uid | device_type | account_id | id_device | timestamp | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | device1 | uid1 | type1 | 1 | 1 | some time | some value | some value | saome value |
| 2 | device2 | uid2 | type1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

So if there is no data in device_data for device2, the query should capture the device anyway and output the non-existing value from device_data as NULL.

Comment: It's called `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: LEFT JOIN gives me NULL for all device_data values even if the first device has values in it.

Comment: Then you join them wrong.

Comment: I know that too, if I knew how to do it right, I wouldn't be asking about it here.

Comment: "LEFT JOIN gives me NULL for all device_data values even if the first device has values in it".   Please share some data to show this behavior.  (Here or a [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/saistHUO))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need LEFT JOIN, to get all device records in output, with all device_data records, if any

```
select * from devices d left join device_data dd on dd.id_device=d.id
```

but also I see from your query, that you want to select only latest row from device_data for each device, so you should do it like this:

```
select *
from devices d
left join device_data dd on dd.id_device_id=d.id
where not exists (select 1 from device_data where id_device=dd.id_device and 
timestamp>dd.timestamp)
```

(you can place this "not exists" condition in ON clause as well)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I have come to the following result.
This query is much faster (0.0022s vs. 0.1945) than the one mentioned by @kergma.

```
SELECT * FROM devices AS d 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM device_data d WHERE d.timestamp = (SELECT max(d2.timestamp) FROM device_data d2 WHERE d2.id_device=d.id_device))
AS dd ON d.id = dd.id_device;
```